# I'm having this error when I check the console :"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

My d3.js objects don't appear as well. How do I fix this?
I am learning d3.js for a project. I intend to use it to make an interactive visual that gets its data from multiple csv files.

```
<html>
    <title>Loans</title>
    <head>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js" charset="utf-8"></script>



    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        var canvas = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width".500)
                .attr("height".500);
        var circle= canvas.append("circle")
                .attr("cx",1000)
                .attr("cy",1250)
                .attr("r",100000)
                .attr("fill","blue");
    })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using periods instead of commas here:

```
.attr("width".500)
.attr("height".500);
```

Comment: Thank you so much!